# How to handle convertion after method call

Tags: java-8, java-stream

It's common to make a method with the common parts for example

```
public List<SomeObjDto> getSomeObject(final String s) {
    List<SomeObj> someList = someRepo.getSome(s);
    return toDto(someList);
}

public List<SomeObjDto> getSomeOtherObject(final String s) {
    List<SomeObj> someList = someRepo.getSomeOther(s);
    return toDto(someList);
}

private List<SomeObjDto> toDto(final List<SomeObj> list) {
    return list.stream()
            .map(SomeConverter::convert)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

So instead of writing the map and the collect the toDto method exists.
Is there a way to not have that method enclosing the result? for example write it like

```
 return someRepo.getSome(s).stream.toDto();
```

or like

```
 return someRepo.getSome(s).andThen(toDto());
```

What would be the changes necessary to getsome or to toDto to make this possible?(or something similar to this)

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: You seem to be focusing on how the source code looks like, i.e “have that method enclosing the result”, which is nonsense. Of course, you could write `return someRepo.getSome(s).stream() .map(SomeConverter::convert).collect(Collectors.toList());` instead, but this is no improvement over the code you have now, which avoids the duplication of common code.

Comment: @Holger very, true, but shouldn't the code be readable? is the statement "return toDto(someRepo.getSome(s));" readable? Maybe but just because the method name is very short and only has 1 param. I wanted something more readable, is that a bad thing?

Comment: This is an ordinary method invocation with an expression providing the argument. There is nothing unreadable here, but if you think these two expressions should be separated, you can use a local variable like you already did in the question’s code example. That’s ok, some people prefer such a separation, so there’s no other syntactical variant necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were determined not to use `toDto` method directly (like you do now), you could write a custom [mapping collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) like that:

```
static Collector<SomeObj, ?, List<SomeObjDto>> toDtos() {
    return Collectors.mapping(SomeConverter::convert, Collectors.toList());
}
```

whose usage would leave you with the following:

```
public List<SomeObjDto> getSomeObject(final String s) {
    List<SomeObj> someList = someRepo.getSome(s);
    return someList.stream().collect(toDtos());
}

public List<SomeObjDto> getSomeOtherObject(final String s) {
    List<SomeObj> someList = someRepo.getSomeOther(s);
    return someList.stream().collect(toDtos());
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this was mostly an experiment to see how far I can take things to understand where the boundaries lie

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 return toDto(someRepo.getSome(s));
```